# MySQL SELECT * optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

Is there a reason why there is enormous difference between

```
1. SELECT * FROM data;      -- 45000 rows
2. SELECT data.* FROM data; -- 45000 rows

SHOW PROFILES;
+----------+------------+-------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                   |
+----------+------------+-------------------------+
|        1 | 0.10902800 | SELECT * FROM data      |
|        2 | 0.11139200 | SELECT data.* FROM data |
+----------+------------+-------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

As far as I know it, they both return the same number of rows and columns. Why the disparity in duration?

`MySQL version 5.6.29`

Comment: 0.002 seconds is not "enormous".  This difference is probably due to other activity on the server.

Comment: Even if you run the first query twice it will have different times.

Comment: @GordonLinoff To be fair, it's a 2% difference, which could be significant. But I'll bet if he repeated them several times he'll see that sometimes one is faster. But he also needs to make sure to disable the query cache.

Comment: @Barmar It is not significant due to the scale of the problem. We are talking about microseconds. The cpu was busy with other processes, maybe it had a slight different frequency, or maybe it was the data storage who was busy. This difference is normal on that scale. But if the query took minutes, then the 2% difference could be big.

Comment: @Edu It really depends on whether it's consistent. It might be only microseconds because the table is small in his test, but if you scale to a larger table it would be magnified.

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS;` for each query.  You will probably see that the identical code is being performed.

Comment: Rule of Thumb:  Do not focus on performance differences under 10%.

Answer (score 2):

That's not much difference.  Neither are optimized.  Both do full table scans.  Both will parse to the optimizer the same.  You are talking about fractions of milliseconds difference.

You can't optimize full table scans.  The problem is not "select *" or "select data.*".  The problem is that there is no "where" clause, because that's where optimization starts.

Answer (score 1):

The particular examples specified would return the same result and have the same performance. 
[TableName].[column] is usually used to pinpoint the table you wish to use when two tables a present in a join or a complex statement and you want to define which column to use out of the two with the same name.

It's most common use is in a join though, for a basic statement such as the one above there is no difference and the output will be the same.